# Lower bound on $\pi(x/2)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have seen the bound,

$\pi(x/2)^2\gg\frac{x^2}{\log^2x}$

(In particular here http://staff.polito.it/danilo.bazzanella/PhD_files/Not%20always%20buried%20deep%20(Pollack).pdf page 212)
Can someone please justify this.

Comment: if $\gg$ means there exists a constant $C$ and $N$ such that $C\pi(x/2)^2 >  x^2 / \log^2(x)$ for every $x > N$, then it is a very weak version of the prime number, that you can deduce directly from $\ln \zeta(s) \sim -\ln(s-1)$ and probably also from ${n \choose n/2} > \pi(x)-\pi(x/2)$ and $\ln n! = \sum_{p^k \le n} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor \ln p$

Comment: Thank you, I was interpreting the $\gg$ as 'much greater than' this makes more sense!

Comment: @Jthomas I believe the notation is defined at the front of the book.